# How to initialize a variable with slice of pointers to string?

Tags: go

Below is the code:

```
package main

type T struct {
    m1 *string
    m2 *string
    m3 *string
    m4 *string
}

type SliceT  = []*T

func main() {

    sliceT := SliceT{
        {
            m1: "0000000001", // & operator works on variable but not on untyped string constant
            m2: "00000002",
            m3: "abc",
            m4: "def",
        },
        {
            m1: "0001",
            m2: "0000012",
            m3: "aaa",
            m4: "bbb",
        },
        {
            m1: "00003",
            m2: "002",
            m3: "ccc",
            m4: "fff",
        },
    }

}
```

---

How to initialize `sliceT`?  composite literal does not help here..

Answer (score 3):

Use a simple helper:

```
func str(s string) *string {return &s}

...
m1: str("0000000001"),
...
```